# storing queryset in session variables

Tags: python, django, web

I am using django and trying to store the queryset in session variable

```
def wholelist(request):
    hotelvar=request.POST.get('service_type')


    city_list=Hotels.objects.filter(city_name__iexact=request.POST.get('searchabc'))
    if not city_list:
        hotel_list=Hotels.objects.all()
        context={'hotel_list':hotel_list}
        return render(request, 'polls/homepage.html',context)

    pricemin=200
    pricemax=800
    request.session['hlist']=city_list
```

I am getting the following error:
[Hotels: ashoka, Hotels: abc] is not JSON serializable

I tried to convert into list and then store it

```
request.session['hlist']=list(city_list)
```

I am getting the following error:
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'POST'

This is the model structure of hotels

```
class Hotels(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.hotel_name
    hotel_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    photo=models.ImageField()
    city_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Is there a way to store queryset in session variable?

Comment: That code by itself does not give the error. Please show the rest of the view - properly indented - and the *full* traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't save QuerySet direct in Django session , u need to serialize it first then you will be able to save it in session.

Let me know if it working with you 
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

For `is not JSON serializable` error you can serialize your models with django `serializers` as follows:

```
from django.core import serializers

hotel_list=Hotels.objects.all()
json_hotel = serializers.serialize('json', hotel_list)
context={'hotel_list':json_hotel}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I am understanding by your problem is that you want to store all the values returned in a queryset to be stored in the session variable of the request.

But you can not do that as those querysets will be nothing but the reference to the objects.

For if you want to store the values, what you can do is

```
import json
def wholelist(request):
hotelvar=request.POST.get('service_type')


city_list=Hotels.objects.filter(city_name__iexact=request.POST.get('searchabc'))
if not city_list:
    hotel_list=Hotels.objects.all()
    context={'hotel_list':hotel_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/homepage.html',context)

pricemin=200
pricemax=800
city_list2 = []
city_list_for_session = city_list.values()#this will store the values of querylist to the session
for item in city_list_for_session:
    data = {
            'hotel':item['hotel'],
            'city_name':item['city_name']}

    city_list2.append(data)
request.session['hlist']=city_list2
```

The function `.values()` will get you a list of all the items with the value of each column in a dictionary.

So basically what you will be getting is a list of dictionary with the values of queryset.

Hope it helps.

Comment: city_list_for_session = json.dumps(city_list.values())  this is giving the following error: [] is not JSON serializable

Comment: Can you post the model structure for the model hotel.

Comment: added it in the original question

Comment: your ImageField is not json serializable. so you will not able to store the image. Also i dont suggest you to store all the images obtained from filter. Instead what you can do is not put the ImageField in the serialized data.

Comment: Thanks for the help